# Why is AuthLogic so popular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

It seems that a lot of Ruby on Rails questions are related to AuthLogic.  What are the advantages of it that it is so popular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's popular because with Rails 2.2, it was the most complete authentication plugin system.

The authentication is often the base of each web application. It's quickly used on a lot of projects and often beginners start by blindly adding the authlogic plugin. The beginner doesn't understand how it's works, and ask some questions on SO.

There is a new, great, and complete plugin for Rails 2.2 and Rails 3. It's called [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). A lot of people come with questions about it as well.

Each plugin is good, each is different. You just need to choose what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few self-contained user frameworks, and AuthLogic is one of the earliest full-featured varieties. Thoughtbot is also pretty good at marketing their technology, and their other gem, [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), is very popular as well.

The advantage of AuthLogic is that you can get slap on a user authentication system quite easily to an existing application without having to roll your own, something that is challenging for someone unfamiliar with Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Because it works.